# AjaxFileUpload (AjaxControlToolkit.dll v 4.1.7) is not working on server having IIS 7.5. Works fine on local with VS2010

Tags: asp.net, file-upload, ajaxcontroltoolkit

I am using AjaxControlToolkit v 4.1.7 for AjaxFileUpload. It works perfectly fine with VS2010. But when I publish it to server (having IIS 7.5) then it does not work and throws following javascript exception.

```
Message: Sys.ArgumentException: Cannot deserialize empty string.
Parameter name: data
Line: 2
Char: 46199
Code: 0
URI: https://<myurl>/ScriptResource.axd?d=qpkn13nmQAGJYY_Gveoq5ARHdY0TCehkZDQEMdnVowBlqBijifi1VWdbEgPLkyJBLEMm2ksKbX2cc4OByctoJB2nGCznl04HPSU19-
```

Following settings is already there in web.config

```
<add verb="*" path="AjaxFileUploadHandler.axd" type="AjaxControlToolkit.AjaxFileUploadHandler, AjaxControlToolkit"/>
```

Please suggest!!

Answer (score 0):

I think Ajax dll must be present in the root directory of

your project